# Second law of thermodynamics less intuitive

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

The zeroth and first laws of thermodynamics seem like common sense but the second law is not very intuitive- how can someone think of ' the entropy of the universe is always increasing'? Shouldn't laws be very very intuitive: something which you cannot prove but only comes from empirical evidences and understanding of the universe around us?

Comment: If you think physical laws should be intuitive, I assume you haven’t studied relativity yet.  BTW, is it intuitive that heat flows from hot to cold?

Comment: As Bob said, you need to specify what isn't intuitive to you. It's unhelpful to us if you just assert it isn't intuitive. For instance, one could specify that diffraction isn't intuitive because "when they open a door between a dark room and a lit room, the light seems to spread out in the room and fade at the edges at far angles from the door so why do we get totally different behavior when we open a tiny single slit for light to pass through?"  Be specific about what you would EXPECT if it isn't intuitive to you

Comment: Why do you think that your intuition has anything to do with my intuition? Intuition is, perhaps, a biological shortcut within the brain to quickly make sense of things. It is not a rigorous physics-based thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't laws be very very intuitive: something which you cannot
>   prove but only comes from empirical evidences and understanding of the
>   universe around us?

You said the zeroth and first law "seem like common sense". The first law is a statement of conservation of energy, and yes it does make sense since that law is well understood. If energy in the form of heat is transferred from one body to another the first law is satisfied as long as the amount of energy transferred from the first body equals the amount of energy delivered to the second body. Makes sense, right?

But in the above example we also know that the natural *direction* of the energy transfer always is from the warmer body to the cooler body. You might say that fact is "empirical" evidence of the way the world operates. The problem is, the first law and its property "internal energy"  would also be satisfied if the energy flowed naturally from the cooler body to the warmer body. But we never observe that to be the case.

Enter the need for a new law that not only satisfies conservation of energy, but tells us *the direction* in which energy can flow naturally. That's the second law. The property associated with the second law is entropy. It says the change in entropy of the universe (system + surroundings) will always increase for all real processes. The change will be zero for a reversible process. But reversible processes do not exist in reality.

Without getting into the details of the property of entropy, suffice it to say it can be shown that if heat transfer occurred naturally (without external intervention in the form of work) from a cooler body to a warmer body, the overall change in entropy would be less than zero, in violation of the second law. If you need an example to illustrate that point I can provide it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir, this is all what I already know from textbooks. The issue that I was facing was that the 0th and 1st laws seemed so simple, it felt like even I could propose them. But the notions of entropy do not come to you, at least me, very naturally. Sure, I can understand them but it is not something I would be able to come up with spontaneously. The simpler statement which was originally proposed- heat flows from hot to cold IS something I could've proposed. No one told me that Clausius came up with a state variable, entropy, a decade later.

Comment: if it took him a decade, it is unreasonable for me ( an average person ) to expect to come up with entropy in an hour. And then to mold it into a law that the entropy of the universe is always increasing. I get all of this ( the thermodynamic and statistical ( the one about states) interpretations of entropy)  but I couldn't have come up with all of this myself. In fact, heat can flow from cold to hot but it is so improbable, approximately once in 10^26, that it's just close to impossible.

Comment: @prarabdg shivhare since you know it all already I obviously can’t help you. With that I take my leave. Good luck

Comment: Ughh I’m sorry if that was harsh or offensive. I really did not see it while typing. I can be like that. Trying to work on it. Sincere apologies.

Comment: @prarabdh shivhare that’s ok. But you need be more  specific as to what isn’t intuitive about the second law so we can respond

Comment: What is your reasoning behind answering a question you voted to have closed?